# como puedo saber cuando es el ultimo elemento en for

Tags: php, array

tengo un problema en php estoy tratado de saber cuado es el ultimo elemento no se me genere el ultimo elemento que seria

```
   <li class="separator">&nbsp;</li>
    <?php
    $rama_cat="40-20-01";
    $partes=explode('-',$rama_cat);
    $cantidad=count($partes);


    for ($i=0; $i < $cantidad; $i++) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?=$urlWeb;?>"><?=nombre_cat($partes[$i]);?></a></li>
    <?php
    foreach($partes as $elem) {
     if ($elem === reset($partes)) {
    echo '<li class="separator">&nbsp;</li>';
    }
    }
    }?>
```

Comment: si pones cantidad -1 el ultimo no lo tomas en cuenta...

Comment: Voy a revertir tu solucion. Ademas que tenes dos respuestas, la solucion debe ir en el campo de respuestas y no en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto :)

```
$array = ['40','20','01'];
$length  = count($array);

foreach($array as $num=>$elem) {
  echo ($num == $length-1) ? '' : '<li class="separator"> '.$elem.'</li>' ;
}
```

Vamos por partes:

Suponiendo que ya realizaste la función explode a $partes te devuelve un arreglo  como este ( [0] => 40 [1] => 20 [2] => 01 )

```
$array = ['40','20','01'];
```

Ahora vamos a medir la longitud del arreglo con count() y lo guardamos en una variable

```
$length  = count($array);
```

La siguiente parte se podía hacer de muchas formas, pero en este caso vamos a utilizar un foreach y un operador ternario

```
    //comenzamos en ciclo 

    foreach($array as $num=>$elem) {

    //comenzamos a recorrer el array, $num nos servirá para contar el número de vuelta, $elemen contiene los datos del array

   //en esta parte pasamos al operador ternario establecemos nuestra condicional, en este caso le decimos que cuando $num sea igual a el tamaño del array menos 1 no nos imprima nada, de caso contrario imprimirá lo pedido. 

      echo ($num == $length-1) ? '' : '<li class="separator"> '.$elem.' posición  en array => '.$num.'</li>' ;


    }
```

Comment: Añade una explicación a tu código

Comment: Listo, ahora todo se entiende más claro.

Comment: Como detalle, Indicar que estais suponiendo (porque el ejemplo es asi) que las keys en el foreach son numeros enteros, y por eso contais hasta el anterior. En el caso de que las keys fueran cadena, el foreach deberia ir hasta el penuntimo key.

Answer (score -1):

Si te fijas en esta parte:

```
$cantidad=count($partes);
```

Si $partes tiene 3 elementos, entonces estarán en la posición 0,1,2 y count($partes) te dará 3; si tiene 10 elementos, estarán en la posición: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 respectivamente, y además, count($partes) te dará 10. Si te fijas, el último elemento siempre estará en `count($partes) - 1`